# PyGOBject referring to instance of same class

Tags: python, pygobject, gobject

I am creating a `Python3` application using PyGOBject for its `Gtk3` and `Gstreamer` bindings. One of my classes needs to have a property which refers to an instance of the same type (or subclass) of the class

```
from gi.repository import GObject

class Cue(GObject.GObject):
    # ...

    autofollow_target = GObject.Property(type=Cue, default=None)

    # ...

    def __init__(self):
        GObject.GObject.__init__(self)
```

However, the python parser returns the following error for this particular snippit of code:

```
NameError: name 'Cue' is not defined
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with how python creates its classes, because I was able to create a property of a different custom type.

Comment: class's name is not known before the class is completely defined. you can create autofollow_target in __init__ method after super call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use `gobject.TYPE_OBJECT` or simply `object` for the type information:

```
from gi.repository import GObject

class Cue(GObject.GObject):
    # ...

    autofollow_target = GObject.Property(type=object)

    # ...

    def __init__(self):
        GObject.GObject.__init__(self)
```

I haven't yet figured out how to specify that a property is an object of a specific type, but I think that may be a problem with the bindings themselves

Comment: Note that using type=object is a bit different than type=GObject.TYPE_OBJECT (or type=GObject.Object). The former of using "object" is actually equivalent to GObject.TYPE_PYOBJECT. With "object", *any* Python object is acceptable whereas with GObject.Object, only GObjects will work, which is probably closer to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are trying to use the class's own name inside itself. In Python, the class's name is not known before the class has been fully defined/instantiated.

One workaround for the same can be adding this in your class before assigning your property and then calling this property method:

```
@property
def __class_name__(cls):
    return type(cls)
```

So your code would be:

```
from gi.repository import GObject

class Cue(GObject.GObject):
    # ...

    @property
    def __class_name__(cls):
        return type(cls)

    autofollow_target = GObject.Property(type=__class_name__, default=None)

    # ...

    def __init__(self):
        GObject.GObject.__init__(self)
```

*Note:* I have not tested this.

Hope that was useful.

Comment: This will throw a TypeError

Comment: I tested a generic code implementing the technique and it seemed to work fine @Padriac. Are you saying it will throw `TypeError` in the context of `gi`?

Comment: Yes, as far as I see there are only certain types accepted

Comment: Oh, strange. @techwiz24 mentioned in the question that he could use other custom types though.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I tested it like this: http://pastebin.com/ALAASVtj and it seemed to work. Assuming that @techwiz24 problem statement saying that "was able to create a property of a different custom type.", it should not throw a type error. Then again, I have not tested this using `GObject`. Thank you for the info though.

Comment: I just tested it  and it does throw a TypeError, `TypeError: Unsupported type: <function Cue.__class_name__ at 0x7fcf1b2bed08>`, I wondered as I did not see anything about custom types in the docs, I see `str` etc.. being passed but nothing about custom classes, http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/objects.html#properties

Comment: Oh! In that case, I got nothing. Thank for clarifying this, @PadriacCunningham! I guess it's upto @techwiz24 to try it out in the context of his/her code/version. Do you think it probably only accepts types or subtypes of standard Python built-in types?

Comment: I may be wrong  but looking at the source it seems that  there is a  `self._type_from_python(type)` check and the error  raised is `raise TypeError("Unsupported type: %r" % (type_,))`, it  may also be because a function is not expected but either way I think the OP is going to struggle with this approach

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, this does indeed throw a type error for me. kartikg3, when I mentioned custom types, I meant other classes that have already been defined.

Comment: @techwiz24, I imagine you need to have your custom type/class  already created.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That is correct. I suppose I could wrap the class in a short wrapper class and then use that wrapper class as the type, but that sounds ugly. I think I may just specify the property in the initializer as laltin mentioned in his/her comment.

Comment: @techwiz24, you should look at this method from the source http://pastebin.com/ZgpyaaGL

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks. It appears that it is happy with `gi.repository.GObject.TYPE_OBJECT`. I'm going to flesh out the program a tad more and if I don't run into any other issues, I'll add an answer here. Thanks everyone for the help! Also, it appears I lied earlier. I couldn't use custom classes that have already been defined, the interpreter just never got that far :O

Comment: @techwiz24, no worries we will forgive you this time ;)

Comment: The reason the solution here doesn't work is because PyGObject uses a custom meta-class which registers sub-types with the GObject type system *after* it is fully parsed. Properties can only be of registered GTypes which isn't the case at the time it is being used. As an aside, I would avoid using custom "dunder" names on Python classes (`__class_name__`).